# Регулярные выражения Python - значение из середины текста

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью регулярных выражений (желательно в Python) извлечь значение "3", используя только "А" в выражении. Каждое значение находится на новой строке.

Пробую следующим образом, но не работает:

```
text = """

A

ab

1

2

bc

3

4

B

ab

5

6

bc

7

8

"""

re_result = re.search('A.*bc\n+(\d)', text, re.S)
print(re_result.group(1))
```

Выдает 7, а не 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте ленивый поиск, добавив `?`:

```
re_result = re.search('A.*?bc\n+(\d)', text, re.S)
```

Т.к. у вас несколько `bc` и жадный поиск, то регулярка дошла до последнего `bc` и честно вытащила последующее число – `7`.

Пример:

- `.*` – это жадный. Он попробует найти как можно больше.
- `.*?` – это ленивый. Он остановится на первом совпадении.