# Как убрать весь мусор кроме конкретней строки после парсинга?

Tags: python

Если вам непонятно что я пишу, прощу прощения за непонятные ошибки, я глухой. 
Я новичок в Python после перехода из php. У меня такой код в Python, после парсинга с помощью regexp выдает все мусорные строки и найденную строку. Как оставить только НАЙДЕННУЮ строку? Спасибо за внимание.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

url = 'https://www.stormo.tv/embed/368013/'
values = {'s':'basics',
            'submit':'search'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()
get_file = re.search('(https://www.stormo.tv/get_file/(.*).mp4)', str(respData))
print(get_file.group(1))
```

Comment: get_file.group(0) не пробовали?

Comment: @danilshik выдает также!

Comment: Это не мусор, это и есть полное совпадение по введённой вами регулярке — в начале `https://www.stormo.tv/get_file/` присутствует и в конце `.mp4` тоже есть, а между ними — произвольное число любых симолов, как вы и написали

Comment: Подозреваю, вы хотели не жадный, а ленивый поиск, и вместо `(.*)` вам нужно написать `(.*?)`

Comment: @andreymal заработало, спасибо тебе, выручил! Понятно в PHP по поводу такой рег. выражении не похоже на Python.

Comment: В таком случае выглядит как дубликат вопроса [Регулярные выражения Python - значение из середины текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868785/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-python-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0), просто текст немного другой

Comment: @andreymal совпадение вопросов не нашлось, но обязательно буду знать в дальнейшем! Спасибо еще раз.